# PHP - Extract current directory and filename from file path

Tags: php, regex

I need to turn this:

`/home/me/public_html/folder1/folder2/folder3/script.php`

Into:

`folder3/script.php`

So far, I have tried using:

`(\/.+\/.+\.php)$`

However the end result is the entire path is returned. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Replace `.+`s with `[^\/]+`s

Comment: The dot `.` will also match the slash `/`. Change your regular expression to exclude the dot: `(/[^/]+/[^/]+\.php)$`. Also, use http://php.net/manual/function.dirname.php instead.

Comment: [Here is how you may use a regex](https://ideone.com/aA2SbU) here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$path='/home/me/public_html/folder1/folder2/folder3/script.php';
$pathinfo=pathinfo($path);
$a=explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$pathinfo['dirname']);
$dir=end($a);
echo $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$pathinfo['basename'];
```

Comment: I think using `explode('/'..` is simpler

Comment: Simpler, but not cross-platform.

Comment: @coladict For example ...?

Comment: @Mohammad Windows CLI.

Comment: Good job I'm using Linux then, as per the directory structure in the initial post!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
$pathinfo=pathinfo('/home/me/public_html/folder1/folder2/folder3/script.php');
$a=explode('/',$pathinfo['dirname']);
echo $dir=end($a);
echo $pathinfo['basename'];
?>
```